# Highlight a word from a URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`.So, Here I have a requirement that I have to highlight some words from a html document.Suppose it's a resume in a html format.So, I have an array of words from that html document which I need to highlight. So, I am able to highlight all the words except the words which are in the url. For e.g. In my document the

```
http://www.example.com
```

So here I want to highlight a word example .

My highlight method is like -

```
$scope.highlightHTML = function (content, text, className, notByWordBoundry) {
    var RegExpEscapeText, str;
    if (!(content && content.replace)) {
        return '';
    }
    if (!text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
    }
    if (!className) {
        className = 'mark';
    }
    RegExpEscapeText = text.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
    if (!notByWordBoundry) {
         str = new RegExp('(\\b)' + RegExpEscapeText + '(\\b)', 'gi');
    } else {
         str = new RegExp(RegExpEscapeText, 'gi');
    }
    return content.replace(str, '<span tabindex="1" class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
};
```

At this time It is messing up the html file while trying to highlight a word which is from the link or url . How can I resolve this ?

Comment: See the [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) examples.

Comment: @dude getting Mark is not defined error.

Comment: Then you haven't installed it or have included it wrong.

Comment: I have installed it using the bower and  also included

Comment: Is it included in the HTML page? Open the developer tools and open the network tab to check it.